# Limit AngularJS use to one domain

Tags: php, angularjs, api, oauth, jwt

I'm writing an AngularJS app that talks to a php api.
Is there a way to prevent users to make api calls directly, without going through the Angular app that sits on one particular domain.
So they have to visit my domain, where the angularjs sits, and only make calls to the api through the Angular app.
I know because it's client side that all code is inspectable.
My app has a public part, and a part that's only available after user login.
So I could easily secure the calls after user login, through OAuth or JWT, but I want to secure the entire thing, including the public part that doesn't need user login.

Is this actually possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is ultimately not. A ***public*** API is ***public***. It receives HTTP requests and returns HTTP responses. HTTP requests are devoid of context. What you want to restrict is that only clients which currently have your specific website open may send those specific HTTP requests to you. That is nonsense. An HTTP request is an HTTP request, regardless of what else is currently going on on the client.

Yes, you could inspect the `Referer` header, but that's just an arbitrary HTTP header anyone can add to their request by hand.

Look at it differently: what if you wrote your site not using Angular and a separate data API, but returned good old HTML pages? Would you require that only specific people can see that HTML? You can't. It's nonsense. Just because you're packaging your data delivery differently doesn't change that.

Comment: Okay I was afraid of that. Thanks.